# Spring Transaction with Sybase

Tags: spring, serialization, sybase, transactions

I am using Spring in my Web Application , with the underlying database as Sybase.

I have 3 complex stored procedures to be executed. 
The procs , have **create table** and **drop table** commands to hold temporary result sets.

The tables are created in the user db space , rather that in the tempdb space. Hence, I am faced with the need to ensure that the entire service operation from the service bean , that would have DAO objects calling the stored procs, to be serialized. Does simply making the service bean method a Spring Transaction, ensure a solution to potential concurrency related problems in my case?

Another thing that I noticed is that, annotating my service method as @Transactional , made the sybase database throw an error : "Create table command cannot be executed within a transaction". Does this mean that Spring makes the entire database operation a transaction?
I am really not clear about this , and any explanation would be welcome.
Meaning if I have a stored proc named **myproc** . The sybase statement would be **exec myproc**. This,say, is executed by the DAOobject from the service method, annotated as @Transactional. Now does Spring make the database operation as "**begin tran 
exec myproc 
end tran**". My observation seems to suggest that. Please explain.

And also explain, if just annotation of @Transactional , will solve my concurrency issues. I , actually don't want 2 instances of my stored proc to be running on the database , at a time.

Comment: Do the names of the tables that are created start with a # symbol?  Are the names fixed, or are they somehow generated on a per-request basis?

Comment: The tables are not prefixed # , i.e the tables are created in the user  db space, rather than the tempdb space. The names are fixed, though the table schema is generated dynamically through dynamic sql, based on the request.

Comment: DDL (like create and drop table statements) typically does an implicit commit so you cannot do that as part of a transactional statement hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a number of questions at once, but I'll do the best I can to answer them.

- Marking a service as @Transactional associates it with the current JTA (Java Transaction API) transaction (or creates one if required)
- Depending on how your datasources are configured, JDBC connections will typically also be associated (enlisted) into the transaction
- If a connection is associated with a JTA transaction then anything that is executed on it will take place within a database transaction.
- In Sybase ASE, you cannot create (or drop) a table inside a transaction.

So, marking your service as @Transactional will prevent you from executing a proc that contains create table statements.

However, that won't solve the problem you're facing anyway.
Marking something @Transactional, simply means that it executes inside a JTA transaction. And that means that it either commits, or rolls-back, but it doesn't guard against concurrent access.

You have a few options

- If you know that your application will only ever run on a single VM, then you can mark the code as `serialized`. This will make sure the VM only ever has 1 thread inside that code at a time.
- You can implement concurrency controls inside the proc, (e.g. use `lock table`), but that will require a transaction, which will prevent you from creating a table inside the procedure.
- Or you can redesign your application to not have to jump through all these hoops.

There are probably easier ways of achieving the outcome you're looking for - creating and dropping tables inside a proc, and then trying to prevent concurrent access to that proc is not a typical way of solving a problem.